# Entity Framework relationship between another fields than id

Tags: entity-framework, relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I have two class (tables)
`Person { id(primary key) , code, name, address, ...}
Order {id(primary key) , order_number, customer, create_date, description, ...}`

I want to create relationship between `Person.code` and `Order.customer` (one two many).
How can I create that relationship in EF code first.

Comment: What's the logic for that approach? Is Person.code unique? If so, why don't you make it the Id. If not, why do you want to have that relation instead of Order.customer mapping to Person.Id?

Comment: Yes Person.code is unique, person.id is AI field but sometimes I need to change Person.code so I don't want to use person.id in Order table.

Comment: Personally I would map through the Id and use the navigation property to access the code like Order.Customer.Code

Comment: maybe it needs a little play with modelBuilder in OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)

Comment: That wasn't possible in previous versions of EF. I know now that you can set a property as unique (which you always need to do on that Person.code). But then, not sure if EF supports association for non key properties.

Comment: Also, in proper normalised database you would map the primary key of the person (id) and not any other column (code).

Answer (score 0):

OK it has an easy solution

```
[Table("Person")]
public partial class Person
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Key()]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string code { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string address{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

and for order

```
[Table("Order")]
public partial class Order
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public int order_number { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string customer { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    //...

    [ForeignKey("customer")]
    public Library Person { get; set; }
}
```

*I will create a new question about specification various composite keys per each navigation property.*